# Using multiple CUDA GPUs

Tags: cuda

I'm using NVIDIA Grid K2 for CUDA programming. It has two GPUs, each with 1536 cores.
Is it possible to utilize both GPUs in a single or multiple kernel calls?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Each GPU on a multi-GPU card like a Grid K2 is a separate CUDA device with its own memory. As such, each GPU gets its own CUDA context and must be explicitly programmed. The CUDA driver or runtime will not automagically use both devices as a single virtual device for a kernel launch.

Comment: is the memory at least shared? ie. can i copy data from host to device0 and then run a kernel on device1 that will use the data from device0? or do i have to copy the data to each one separately? or is it at least possible to copy data directly between devices (from dev0 to dev1)?

Comment: @ValCool: As far as I am aware the answer is no, the memory is not shared. On supported platforms it is possible to used unified virtual memory and peer-to-peer memory access, but the two discrete GPUs are only linked by a common PCI-e bridge chip on the board, and communication is basically at PCI-e DMA speeds

Comment: so the SLI is not used for this kind of communication?

Comment: @ValCool: No. CUDA has nothing to do with SLI. As I have had it explained to me, the SLI link is basically a relatively low bandwidth, low latency link for framebuffer synchronisation between display devices. The memory behaviour of a dual GPU card in SLI *mode* on Windows is different because the driver seems to use the same PCI-e level peer-to-peer processes CUDA uses to keep Direct3D or OpenGL context objects synchronised between the GPUs. But they are still, under those levels of abstraction, two discrete devices sitting on a PCI-e switch.

Comment: I'm using Cudafy.NET and just found a function which copies data from one GPU device to the other: `_gpu0.CopyDeviceToDevice(_gpuuintBufferIn0, 0, _gpu1, _gpuuintBufferIn1, 0
, _uintBufferIn0.Length);`
Do you think, it first copies the data to host memory inside, before moving it to the other device?